# I want to replace alternate occurrences of a substring from a string using python

Tags: python, string

I have a string. I want to replace every alternate substring with a new substring so that in the below string 1st and 3rd occurrences of `xx` should change to `rr`.

```
#------------------------------------------------------ 
import re
str1="abcxxhghxxjjhxxjjhj"
cnt=0
for i in re.finditer("xx",str1):
    cnt=cnt+1    
    if cnt%2!=0:
        print(cnt)
        l=i.span()[0]
        m=i.span()[1]
        print(l,m)
        str1=re.sub(str1[l:m],"rr",str1)
    
print(str1)
```

Expected output : `abcrrhghxxjjhrrjjhj`

Answer (score 7):

We can actually handle this with a single call to `re.sub`:

```py
str1 = "abcxxhghxxjjhxxjjhj"
output = re.sub(r'xx(.*?)(xx|$)', r'rr\1\2', str1)
print(output)  # abcrrhghxxjjhrrjjhj
```

The strategy is to find `xx` followed by the nearest `xx`, then replace the first `xx` with `rr`, leaving the remaining content alone.  Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```regex
xx      match 'xx'
(.*?)   match and capture all content up until
(xx|$)  the nearest next 'xx' OR the end of the input
```

Then, we replace with `rr\1\2`, changing only the leading `xx` into an `rr`.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
for i in re.finditer("xx",str1):
    cnt=cnt+1    
    if cnt%2!=0:
        str1 = str1[:i.start()] + "rr" + str1[i.start() + 2:]
```

slicing the string with the re.finditer index

Comment: But prefer the answer above which should be way more efficient